# Converting Units and Formatting using the MeasurementFormatter SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Hello I’m really new to SwiftUI and especially converting uints. I’m trying to convert `inches` to `feet` and then use the `MeasurementFormatter()` to display the value as `feet` rather than a decimal. For some reason, I keep getting an error in my code when trying to assign my output value the string from the `formatter`. Would love any suggestions anyone has.

Func Code:

```
func convertToFeet() {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        var distanceInFeet = Measurement(value: Double(inputValue) ?? 0, unit: UnitLength.inches)
        distanceInFeet.convert(to: UnitLength.feet)
        //formatter.unitStyle = MeasurementFormatter.UnitStyle.long
        formatter.string(from: distanceInFeet) // 3,626.81 miles
        
        outputValue = formatter.description
    }
```

[image: this is my function]

All Code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  AC Converstion
//
//  Created by Luke Jamison on 11/7/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import Foundation


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var inputValue = ""
    @State private var outputValue = ""
    @State var value: Double = 0
    @State var length: Measurement = .init(value: 1, unit: UnitLength.inches)
    private var massFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("\(outputValue)").font(.title2)
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Inches to Feet")) {
                        TextField("Enter Inches", text: $inputValue).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.convertToFeet()
                        }, label: {
                            Label("Convert", systemImage: "car")
                        })
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Convert")
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    func convertToFeet() {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        var distanceInFeet = Measurement(value: Double(inputValue) ?? 0, unit: UnitLength.inches)
        distanceInFeet.convert(to: UnitLength.feet)
        //formatter.unitStyle = MeasurementFormatter.UnitStyle.long
        formatter.string(from: distanceInFeet) // 3,626.81 miles
        
        outputValue = formatter.description
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general the `description` property in Swift should only be used for debug purposes.  Its value isn't guaranteed to be consistent over different versions of a particular class.

The correct way to get a string value from a measurement formatter is to call the `string(from:)` function as you are doing.  This function returns a string.  You aren't doing anything with the string value that is returned which is what the compiler is warning you about.

Rather than relying on a side-effects, I would change your function to accept an input parameter and return a value.

You will also need to set the formatter's `unitOptions` property to `.providedUnit` to ensure you get output in feet;  If you don't then you will get a locale-specific output (ie kilometres in metric locales)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var inputValue = ""
    @State private var outputValue = ""
    @State var value: Double = 0
    @State var length: Measurement = .init(value: 1, unit: UnitLength.inches)
    private var massFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("\(outputValue)").font(.title2)
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Inches to Feet")) {
                        TextField("Enter Inches", text: $inputValue).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.outputValue = self.convertToFeet(inches: self.inputValue)
                        }, label: {
                            Label("Convert", systemImage: "car")
                        })
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Convert")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func convertToFeet(inches: String)-> String {
        
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        
        var distanceInFeet = Measurement(value: Double(inches) ?? 0, unit: UnitLength.inches)
        
        distanceInFeet.convert(to: UnitLength.feet)
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit

        return formatter.string(from: distanceInFeet)
    }
    
}
```